# Linux + Wine can not connect to SQL Server by System.Data.SqlClient with error about handshake in provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - SSL provider

Tags: .net, sql-server, linux, ssl, wine

i have a windows forms app (.net framework 4.0), that connect to SQL Server by System.Data.SqlClient. I'd like to use this provider. I can connect by Odbc, but in my program may be too hard to change main provider, so i'd like to stay with System.Data.SqlClient.

Everything works fine in Windows, but when I try to use Linux with Wine I get error

> A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - SSL provider: )

I had installed in my wine (and framework ofcourse)

```
winetricks mdac28 native_mdac
```

and odbc provider in my Linux
I use Ubuntu 20.04, but got same error in other Debian like version
I use SQL Server 2016, installed on Windows 2016. No enforce encryption enabled in SQL Server.

I read that Wine cannot set SSL connections to SQL Server, but I have no idea, how I can avoid it, and have no idea, why it try to use it, against I don't use SSL encryption at all.
Could you give me advise, what I can do to avoid this error and establish connection.

Comment: Probably a TLS 1.2 issue, does Wine support it? What is your connection string, and are you *sure* the `Enforce Encryption` setting is off?

Comment: My connection is simple `<add name="name" connectionString="Data Source=server ip, port;Initial Catalog=dbname;Connection Timeout=30;Connection Timeout=3;User ID=user;Password=pass;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>` I tried with and without Encrypt and TrustServerCertificate keys. Same error. And yes, I'm sure, encryption is off.

Comment: `Encrypt=True;` ??? Removing that should remove your problem for the moment, although it's better to have an encrypted connection. I suggest you also investigate why Wine is not allowing TLS. For `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` you need to explicitly set `Encrypt=False;`

Comment: It does not matter. With or without this key. Error is the same. This key just show to client not ask certificate of SSL for encrypted connections. But I get same error independently use or not use this key.

Comment: I tried `Encrypt=False;` it gives same error.

Comment: Well `Encrypt=false;` in the connection string completely turns off encryption for that particular SQL connection, so if you're still getting an SSL Provider error then it must be coming from somewhere else. Do you have multiple connection strings in the .config file? Is there a connection string embedded in code instead of the .config file? Do you have code using a [SqlConnectionStringBuilder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder)?

Comment: I made simple project with one connection string in app, it just tries establish connection. It creates connection by `DbConnection cnn = dbFactory.CreateConnection();` where dbFactory is an object gotten by `DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(provider)` where provider is a name of `System.Data.SqlClient` . So I'm totally sure about simplicity of my setup. But still getting error.